# Add an HTML element conditionally

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to add an HTML element into a div, only after checking the condition. I tried with conditionally adding a directive and append element, but I couldn't.

Comment: '<div ng-if="condition" ng-include="path_url"></div>' use this

Comment: @anoopmm : i am trying to add some html element... i don't have path

Comment: or use ng-bind-html  reffer this http://plnkr.co/edit/BIIccWSIlOqd5wW3oQ5Y?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You have two options: The `ng-show` and the `ng-if` directive:

## [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

The `ng-show` directive shows or hides elements respectively by adding or removing the `ng-hide` CSS class, to or from the element.

**Basic example:**

```
<div id="someDiv" class="myDivClass" ng-show="myCtrl.user.attribute == true"></div>
```

## [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

The `ng-if` directive actually deletes and recreates the element. Note that an element with the `ng-if` directive has its own scope, which is destroyed when the element is deleted from the DOM.

**Basic example:**

```
<div id="someDiv" class="myDivClass" ng-if="myCtrl.user.attribute == true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

```
<div>
    <span ng-if="x == 1">Conditional element</span>
</div>
```